# Desktop sometimes locks up/freezes. What are some common log files,etc I can look at for troubleshooting?

Tags: gnome, 20.04, xorg, ubuntu-gnome, wayland

[image]I'm running the most current release of stock Ubuntu 20.04.  The only desktop extensions I have installed are what comes out of box with Ubuntu. I have an AMD GPU, using out of box Ubuntu AMD drivers that were automatically installed when I first loaded 20.04.  It doesn't happen very often but once in a blue moon my desktop locks up.  This has happened under Wayland and Xorg.  Any pointers on what I can look up (log files, etc) on why this sometimes happens?

When I run free, for Swap I see the following:
Total: 2097148
Used: 0
Free: 2097148
and no entries/values in the Shared, Buff/Cache, and available columns

Comment: Do you have `swap` defined? `free` will tell you. Read `man free mkswap swapon`. Read `man journalctl`, and do `sudo journal --since="-5 minutes"` within 4 minutes of a lockup.

Comment: When I run free, for Swap I see the following:
Total: 2097148
Used: 0
Free: 2097148
and no entries/values in the Shared, Buff/Cache, and available columns

Comment: Please edit your post to add new information, properly formatted. Information added via comments is hard for you to format, hard for us to read, ignored by AskUbuntu's indexing system, and ignored by future readers. Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our uplink to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]

Comment: [Edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1277182/edit) and show me `free -h` and `sudo lshw -C memory` and `sysctl vm.swappiness` and `top`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them. Let me know when you have done the edit.

Comment: @waltinator OP can't do `sudo journal --since="-5 minutes"` after a lockup. Also please change your use of *"since that's our uplink to you"*, as comments are normally a **bi-directional communication** between the OP and other contributing users. Thanks :-)

Comment: Sorry, typo, "`sudo journalctl  --since="-5 minutes"`".